# Google Desktop shortcut Ctrl + Ctrl weird behavior

Tags: 10.04, shortcuts, google-desktop

Just noticed a weird behavior of Google Desktop shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. This shortcut is supposed to bring Google Desktop search bar to the front.

1. If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed the search bar appears, but once you release one of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys it will disappear.
2. If you hold one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and press the other **twice** the search bar will **toggle** it's state.

Do you have any idea how this can be fixed and what can be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Try setting the shortcut to something like left ctrl + right alt, and tell us what happens then. maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that there was always unstable results when I used Google Desktop in 10.04 and 10.10 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. And I've never left the shortcut key for Google Desktop with its default.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is unpractical any way.

So I always change the shortcut key to something else and Google Desktop works fine. Use  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for example.

**You can change it in the preference:**

[image]